# initialized the value of a pointer in declaring process

Tags: c, pointers

something in the pointer confuse me
to declare a pointer to int and then define it

```
int *p, a;
p = &a;
a = 3;
```

it can be changed into

```
int a = 3;
int *p = &a;
```

I'm confused in the latter case. Isn't the value of *p is the value of the object which p point to ( the value of a in this example) so why in the former case it's

```
int *p = &a;
```

which is the address of a but not the value of a. Shouldn't it be

```
int p = &a
```

in order to state that p is the pointer and the address it point to is the address of the object a

Additionally, I see in some case there is (int*) p. Does it have any different to normal declaration?

Comment: `int p` means `p` is an `int`, not a pointer. `int *p` means `p` is a pointer to `int`. Re-read the chapter on pointers.

Answer (score 2):

`*` in declaration

```
int *p = &a;
```

is not an indirection operator. It just inform the compiler that `p` is a pointer type. `*` acts a dereferencing operator only when it appears in a statement. This means that `*p` in `int *p = &a;` is not same as `*p` as an alias of `a`.